# Can I save image and image mime type into one column in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

Can I save image and image mime type into one column in Microsoft SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the type of most images by looking at the first few bytes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)